# Face recognition for Lie Detection

Tags: data-request

Can anybody help find open dataset with Face recognition for Lie Detection with micro-movements detection?
For example i just want find datasets from any of this articles
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/papers/perezrosas.icmi15.pdf
RU-FACS-1 database

https://inc.ucsd.edu/mplab/wordpress/index.html%3Fp=80.html
CASME database:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6553799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper you posted a link to literally states:

> *The dataset introduced in this paper is available upon request.*

and all of the email addresses of the authors are on the title page. In general, for specific and academic datasets, make the request to the researcher first.

---

Note: one author has a download page, but it seems this dataset is not there. http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/downloads.html

Comment: may i ask you help me find  data from  this article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11042-017-5317-2

Comment: @DataMiner - they cite many datasets, some are easily found https://mug.ee.auth.gr/fed/ http://fu.psych.ac.cn/CASME/casme2-en.php